# Remove Existing Account from Firebase 3

Tags: firebase

In pre-Firebase 3, there is a function "removeUser" to remove an existing account with email&password (https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/removeuser.html)

But I can't seem to find a similar function in Firebase 3. Is it no longer possible to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `user.delete()` function. Here is the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#delete_a_user).

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser; 
user.delete().then(function() {
  // User deleted.
}, function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

Note that this is a critical operation and therefore this will need a previous call to `reauthenticate`:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(user.email, userProvidedPassword);

// Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials

user.reauthenticate(credential).then(function() {
  // User re-authenticated.
}, function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

Comment: How is it possible that the syntax in the documentation is so old :D

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp the documentation pointed by the question author is from the legacy 2.x version. Just make sure you look at the [new one](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#delete_a_user) :)